# Alignment in TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have been having alignment issues.The message label keeps over writing the time stamp and the username is disappearing. I have tried the suggested constraints but nothing has worked for me.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        //Transform Data From ^ to load at the bottom
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
        cell?.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
        cell?.accessoryView?.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);

        //Set username label to display username
        let usernameLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        usernameLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].username


        //Set message label to display message
        let messageLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        messageLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].message
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        //initialize UI Profile Image
        let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

        //Make Porfile Image Cirlce
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //Set timeStampLabel to current time AGO
        let timeStampLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
        timeStampLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].timeStamp
        timeStampLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        //Loading and change of Usesrs profile image on chat cell
        let userProfileChatImage = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].photoURL

        //Load profile image(on cell) with URL & Alamofire Library
        let downloadURL = NSURL(string: userProfileChatImage!)
        imageView.af_setImage(withURL: downloadURL as! URL)

        // your cell coding
        return cell!
    }
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsq7j.png)

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWsQQ.png)

```
//TableView Cell word wrap (Dynamic Text)
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 78
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Do i need to set the time stamp label to 0 as well?

```
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: looks like your table cells aren't adjusting their height to accommodate labels with more text. They all look the same size to me in the provided pictures.

In order to really see what the issue is, please post the rest of your tableview code and what constraints you have set.

Comment: Read this might help. http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: I read that article and everything works great until I added the time stamp. What restrictions do i need for it to not get overlapped and space from the messageLabel?

Comment: I think your exactly right on the height adjustment @BJHStudios how can i fix that?

Comment: The table cells are not adjusting their height.

Comment: @codechicksrock can you add what constraints you have give to the components inside `prototype-cell`

Comment: I have added it

Comment: @agent_stack i added me cell code

Comment: give me your email id

Comment: lisedapipr@housat.com

Comment: @codechicksrock check mail i have send you demo regarding this.

Comment: can you post it here? or the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to use labels like you are using and found out about `NSMutableAttributedString()`. There are tons of videos and web pages that explain how it works. If there are people who like a specific one, they can link it in the comments! I use the `attributedString` with a `UITextView` in order to display everything (text-based) that I need. I defer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slGx90YoX3Q&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JE1wErjzEyVqlvx92VN3DL5&index=9) video (beginning at 12:00 mins) on YouTube because it is difficult to explain in text. In order to tackle the problem of creating a `UITableViewCell` that fits varying amounts of text, you will want to drag in a UITextView that does not have a specific width or height constraint. This will allow it to change with the cell. Then, using the code you have...

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 78
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Your cells will dynamically change. One trick to get this working is to do the following steps:

1) Disable user interaction on the `UITextView` using `isUserInteractionEnabled = false`
2) Uncheck `Editable` and `Selectable` in the Interface Builder (Storyboard), as well as unchecking `Scrolling Enabled` in the IB.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already captured all the constraints in that screenshot. I think you missed a **vertical spacing constraint** between timestamp label and message label. After add this constraint, you will also need to change vertical compress resistance and hugging priority for 1 of three labels. I recommend decrease message label's.

Comment: Thank you everyone who contributed! :)